# How Navigate only on Items of current index of ListView?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a `ListView` that has many rows , each row has few `Items`, i want to select one row by up and down keys and then select highlighted row by space or enter key and navigate on its items from first button by up and down keys, how is it possible?

here is my code:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 1.5
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        ListModel
        {
            id:myModel
            ListElement
            {
                text1:"btn1"
                text2:"btn2"
                text3:"btn3"
            }
            ListElement
            {
                text1:"btn1"
                text2:"btn2"
                text3:"btn3"
            }
            ListElement
            {
                text1:"btn1"
                text2:"btn2"
                text3:"btn3"
            }
        }
        ListView {
            id: list
            anchors.fill: parent;
            model: myModel
            currentIndex: 0
            focus: true
            delegate: Rectangle {
                id: delegateItem
                height: 100
                width: parent.width;
                color: "blue"

                Row{
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    Button
                    {
                        text: model.text1
                        height: parent.height

                        onFocusChanged:
                        {
                            if(focus)
                                text="selected"
                            else
                                text= model.text1
                        }
                    }
                    Button
                    {
                        text: model.text1
                        height: parent.height

                        onFocusChanged:
                        {
                            if(focus)
                                text="selected"
                            else
                                text= model.text3
                        }
                    }
                    Button
                    {
                        text: model.text1
                        height: parent.height

                        onFocusChanged:
                        {
                            if(focus)
                                text="selected"
                            else
                                text= model.text3
                        }
                    }
                }
                onFocusChanged:
                {
                    if(focus)
                        delegateItem.color="red"
                    else
                        delegateItem.color="blue"
                }
            }
            Keys.onDownPressed:   {
                if (list.currentIndex + 1 < list.count )
                    list.currentIndex += 1;
            }
            Keys.onUpPressed: {
                if (list.currentIndex  >= 0)
                    list.currentIndex -= 1;
            }
            Keys.onEnterPressed:
            {
                list.currentItem.forceActiveFocus()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you want to select the row? With the mouse? By clicking on one of the buttons or outside of the buttons?

Comment: by Keyboard, i want to select first button of selected row,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For navigating on first button of selected row, you should use `list.currentItem.children` here is modified codes

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 1.5

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        ListModel {
            id: myModel
            ListElement {
                text1: "btn1"
                text2: "btn2"
                text3: "btn3"
            }
            ListElement {
                text1: "btn1"
                text2: "btn2"
                text3: "btn3"
            }
            ListElement {
                text1: "btn1"
                text2: "btn2"
                text3: "btn3"
            }
            ListElement {
                text1: "btn1"
                text2: "btn2"
                text3: "btn3"
            }
            ListElement {
                text1: "btn1"
                text2: "btn2"
                text3: "btn3"
            }
            ListElement {
                text1: "btn1"
                text2: "btn2"
                text3: "btn3"
            }
            ListElement {
                text1: "btn1"
                text2: "btn2"
                text3: "btn3"
            }
        }
        ListView {
            id: list
            anchors.fill: parent
            model: myModel
            currentIndex: 0
            focus: true
            delegate: Rectangle {
                id: delegateItem
                height: 100
                width: parent.width
                color: "blue"

                Row {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    Button {
                        text: model.text1
                        height: parent.height

                        onFocusChanged: {
                            if (focus)
                                text = "selected"
                            else
                                text = model.text1
                        }
                        KeyNavigation.down: list.currentItem.children[0].children[1]
                    }
                    Button {
                        text: model.text1
                        height: parent.height

                        onFocusChanged: {
                            if (focus)
                                text = "selected"
                            else
                                text = model.text3
                        }
                        KeyNavigation.down: list.currentItem.children[0].children[2]
                         KeyNavigation.up: list.currentItem.children[0].children[0]
                    }
                    Button {
                        text: model.text1
                        height: parent.height

                        onFocusChanged: {
                            if (focus)
                                text = "selected"
                            else
                                text = model.text3
                        }
                         KeyNavigation.up: list.currentItem.children[0].children[1]
                    }
                }
                onFocusChanged: {
                    if (focus)
                        delegateItem.color = "red"
                    else
                        delegateItem.color = "blue"
                    console.log(list.currentItem.children[0].children[0].focus)
                }
                Keys.onDownPressed:
                {
                        if (list.currentIndex + 1 < list.count)
                            list.currentIndex += 1
                }
                Keys.onUpPressed:
                {
                        if (list.currentIndex -1 > -1)
                            list.currentIndex -= 1

                }


                Keys.onSpacePressed: {
                    var focus=list.currentItem.children[0].children[children_index].focus
                    list.currentItem.children[0].children[children_index].focus
                            = !focus
                    if(focus)
                        list.currentItem.focus=true
                    console.log("entered: "+list.currentItem.children[0].children[0].focus)
                }
                property int children_index: 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your example, you can select rows by navigating with the arrow keys, and give focus to an individual button by pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> until you get to the one you're interested in. Space activates a button once it has focus.

---

Comparing your answer with the information you added in your third edit, the cleaner way would be to give each button an `id` and refer to that. That is, rather than do this:

```
KeyNavigation.down: list.currentItem.children[0].children[1]
```

which is kinda fragile and difficult to read, do this:

```
KeyNavigation.down: button2
```

Comment: no, i want to start from first button on selected row

Comment: Perhaps you might want to specify that in your question before downvoting answers that are correct given the information you've provided?